# Create .jar file for a website

Tags: java, jar, applet, executable-jar

I have made test.jar file and Applet1.html file both are placed on a web server. test.jar runs perfectly by itself on my local computer but when placed on the server it does not run at all and the following error comes up:

```
Application Error
RuntimeException
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

HTML to call the test.jar

```
<applet 
code="MainClass.class" 
width="400" height="400" 
archive="test.jar"
alt="Error Loading Applet?!" >
</applet>
```

Very basic applet (hello world) works fine but when I make a .jar out of it it does not work.

This link has the [two files used](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/xdnmgnff07z8x4x/gOZTceMZJD):

Could someone help me solve this?

Comment: how exactly are you making the jars?

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace? An InvocationTargetException is just a wrapper and doesn't say an awful lot about what has happened.

Comment: Post a link to the broken applet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
MainClass cannot be cast to java.applet.Applet
```

The `MainClass` which runs so well at home is not an applet.  Double clicking the Jar launches a frame titled "Java Game".

Launch the frame directly from a link using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).